# After Azure Function Successful Deployment, still my URL is not working

Tags: python, api, azure-functions

I have a python code which i used to write in vs code and same i tried to deployed in azure functions to get the endpoint so that i can access it through my bot but that url i have got post deployment is not working.

[image]

The error i am getting is :

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are trying?

Comment: it seems without below module deployment works but unable to see the functions but with these modules it fails ...pytz==2023.3
pywin32==306
pywinpty==2.0.10

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could see that I faced the same issue when `pywin32==306`, `pywinpty==2.0.10` modules are added. Even though I have removed those modules and no error in my code, the URL didn't seem to work.

[image]

*Results:*

[image]

Then I understood that there are module traces in my code which made the function not work. So, I have removed only the above-mentioned packages and deployed once again which gave me expected results as below.

[image]

*Results:*

[image]

Below is the same code I used to reproduce the issue.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"
    sample="abc"
    now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
    print(now_utc.strftime(format))

    now_asia = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
    print(now_asia.strftime(format))

    if len(sample)>0:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"{now_utc} {now_asia}")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```